# PyDrake NLOpt Method Selection

Tags: drake

NLOpt has many different methods implemented as detailed [here](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Tutorial/). I was wondering which one is used by default, and whether I could specify one of them in particular using the SolverOptions interface in `pydrake`.

I've tried, for example,

```
solver = NloptSolver()
options = SolverOptions()
options.SetOption(solver.solver_id(), "algorithm", "LD_LBFGS_NOCEDAL")
```

where I have replaced `"LD_LBFGS_NOCEDAL"` with `"NLOPT_LD_LBFGS_NOCEDAL"`, `"LD_LBFGS"`, etc. (enums taken from [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/988343e69053f2dbc548b744757ffd2c395824c6/tools/workspace/nlopt_internal/patches/gen_enums.patch)) and checked the value of the optimal solution of a highly nonconvex program, which doesn't seem to change no matter what I specify. Is there any way to check whether the option has been set correctly (if it is possible to change it)?

Comment: Currently Drake uses NLOPT_LD_SLSQP. I can add the feature so that the user can specify an algorithm.

BTW, we also provide IPOPT and SNOPT solver interface. Can you solve your problem using these two solvers?

Comment: It would be great to be able to specify the algorithm! I can use SNOPT and IPOPT (and have used both), but the reason I'm asking is because I'm actually doing some benchmarking with different nonconvex program solvers, and it would be helpful to know exactly what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but now Drake can specify the NLOPT algorithm. See https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/18535 for more details.

Comment: Thank you! I have a followup question.

Are there other parameters that are set by default (such as tolerances)? I tried to compare the results by directly using NLOPT's python interface (nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Python_Reference) vs. Drake's NLOPT interface and am not getting the same results.

In particular, when using the NLOPT interface on my problem, the solver hangs, but it terminates with a solution that violates constraints using Drake's interface with the same initial guess. This makes me think there's some differences in settings under the hood.

Comment: Some default parameters are set in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/3d486c2af3e3894791bd728e6f1c343f8ad09ae9/solvers/nlopt_solver.cc#L413-L422